# Is there a high-quality way to run a slide show on MacOS?

Tags: preview, slideshow

Running Mojave on an iMac. My screensaver is set to run a slide show of my favorite photos, and it looks great. Smaller images are zoomed to fit the screen, and a pretty good rescaling algorithm was used.

But if I try to run a slideshow from Preview, the small images are highly pixellated when they're zoomed — no smoothing was done at all. They look terrible.

Is there another way to display a slide show and have it look good? Do I need to install an App from the app store?

I remember when the MacOS built-in slide show mode was much nicer. It's as if they deliberately ruined it to force us all to use some other software.

Comment: "High quality" and "looks good" are subjective. Can you provide more definite criteria for software that would suit you?

Comment: If it looks as good as the screensaver, I'll be happy. Even the most rudimentary smoothing algorithm would help. Right now, it just uses pixel-replication.